# Adding y-ppa Manager

Tags: installation, gnome, ppa

I was wondering if there was any way to add the app called Y-PPA managaer to ubuntu?
[Y-PPA@launchpad.net](https://launchpad.net/y-ppa-manager)

Comment: This kind of questions do no belong here.

Comment: @UriHerrera: Why not? Granted, it's easy enough to find the answer oneself without asking, but we have many such questions here.

Comment: Because i believe he means that Ubuntu should include Y PPA Manager in the default installation.

Comment: It is just not clear what he's asking.

Comment: If he is asking how to add the PPA then launchpad already says how to do it and even shows what to copy/paste in the software sources. I think that even though there are other questions like this here, it might not be a good idea to start creating one question for each PPA and how to install them (There are more than 1000 PPAs). What should be asked would be how to add a ppa and what to know about them like: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them and http://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out

Answer (score 3):

First, add Y PPA Manager's PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
```

Then, install it:

```
sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```